# What is google cloud speech requirement/prerequisite

Tags: google-cloud-speech

is there any additional cost or module that will be required to subscribe/ purchase along with the Speech to text subscription?

Best Regards,
Rami Amr

Answer (score 1):

There's no monthly subscription for Google Cloud Speech but there is a transactional cost for each minute of speech you transcribe to text.